# ArcGIS won't save shapefile after changing folder name

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I was exporting shapefiles to sub-folders (which are inside another folder called `Dimmy`), now, I realized that I had a typo in the folder name, so I changed the name of the `Dimmy` folder to `Dummy`. After that, when I tried exporting a shapefile, it gave the following error. So, I closed ArcScene and opened it again to see if it fixes the error, but it didn't, so I had to change the folder name back to `Dimmy`, and the file exported successfully.

Error:

```
An error occurred trying to save the object named 
"TLS_TP4_Hulls_Species".
```

I am using ArcGIS Desktop version 10.7.1. Basically at first I started exporting shapefiles to this path:

```
~/Dimmy/TP4/
```

The shapefiles get exported to this sub-folder, then I change the folder name so the path changes as follows, and I start getting this error.

```
~/Dummy/TP4/
```

Now, when I revert the path as it was before, the shapefiles get exported to that path without returning this error.

What's causing the error, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: You've clipped the image to remove most of the useful information. Please [Edit] the question to provide more context, starting with the exact release of Desktop in use.

Comment: @Vince, does the question look okay now?

Comment: Not really, no. From where are you exporting? Using which methodology? Originally you stated you were using ArcMap, but now it's ArcScene. Do you have any other tools open in the same filesystems?

Comment: The workflow you followed was, right-click the layer in TOC--> Data-->Export features? If yes, add a screengrab showing the path of the layer in the TOC and the export pane showing the path you selected.